# Cast into BIT Datatype while changing values

Tags: sql, database, select, casting, case

What I want to do is to specify in the query that I want to turn any rating lower than 2 into a 0 and turn any rating greater than 2 into 1 while alltogether casting into BIT datatype

```
select name,lastname from table_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
case when rating > 2 then 1 else 0 end as rating
```

In MySQL, this can be simplified as just:

```
(rating > 2) as rating
```

In your query:

```
select (rating > 2) as rating, name, lastname
from table_name
```

Comment: Can you writte that in a complete query like mine?

Comment: No you are just checking if rating is >2 and returning only those values in the view .What  I want to do is return all the values in the view but converted to BOOL type with CAST

Comment: @Marsal: the query does what you want. Please test it.

Comment: I tested it and first of all I get Incorrect syntax near '>'.